# How to configure url routing if I have duplicate controllers or views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie of the ASP.NET MVC framework
I am just wondering how to configure in my case.

I'd like to make a url in my mvc application as following :

1) http://localhost/statistics/people/index

2) http://localhost/statistics/animal/index

3) http://localhost/information/people/index

4) http://localhost/information/animal/index

if I configure 'statistics' and 'information' as coltrollers, can I make 'people' folder under views folder?

I know that if I use 'area' feature of mvc version 2 framework, but I'd like to know it is possible using mvc 1.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

[Multiple Views in ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/simonince/archive/2008/02/04/multiple-views-with-mvc.aspx)

Update:

You can have two views:
- Views
- Views1

And lets say your url for the first be is say localhost/Category/insert

For me the second url could be localhost/V1/Category/insert

Then you could use ASP.NET to check when a url contains V1, route to Views1/...

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Blend, but I am still wondering if I could solve my problem with just configuration on url routing in global.asax without any extension class